# Maximizing window makes content disappear

Tags: 11.10, unity, window-manager

I am working on a DV9700 HP laptop. I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and the proprietary drivers for the Nvidia Geforce 7150M / nForce 630m.

When maximing ANY window, this means the terminal, nautilus, libreoffice, etc.. the content in the windows disappears. I can resize it again to the default and it will show but if I maximize it the content will disappear.

What can be done in this situation.

Using Unity.

Comment: i think it's an oddity with the driver and unity.  I get weird redraw issues with both the ATI drivers and Nvidia drivers in a couple of situations.  My solution was to select highlight all content in the window to get a redraw.  It's not a fix, but it might get you by

Comment: Yes it also has the same behavior as you mentioned aking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the PPA for nvidia and updating to the latest Nvidia driver has solved the problem.

In the terminal I typed: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Then did an update `sudo apt-get update` and went to the **Update Manager**. Updated the Nvidia driver, rebooted. Tested. Everything works as it should.

I need to add that the same PPA also has Ati drivers. This might solve similar Ati problems.

Comment: That's interesting.  I'll have to try it on the desktop too.  I thought all the funny redraws and screen tearing I was getting was xinerama related since it didn't happen on my laptop.